# What are common code smells that cause Outlook 365 to permanently disable a custom VSTO COM Add-In?

Tags: c#, outlook, .net-4.0, office365

I am currently maintaining a company-internal add in that only takes a mail, wraps it as attachment and sends it to our internal mail adress for spam reports.

The add in always had the issue that for seemingly no reason ( - besides: "the addin has caused outlook to crash - therefore it has been permanently disabled", when checking the addin state)
Outlook doesn't like it and disables it permanently without options to re-enable.

This was already an issue with Outlook 2016, and could back then be solved by setting a few registry keys. I was tasked to build a version for Outlook365. Outlook365 seems to be a lot more sensible there.

I have added a function that sets the following keys:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\Outlook\Addins\SpamReporter]
"LoadBehavior"=dword:00000003

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\Resiliency\DoNotDisableAddinList]
"SpamReporter"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\Addins\SpamReporter]
"LoadBehavior"=dword:00000003
```

The following key is also rolled out via company policy:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Office\16.0\outlook\resiliency\addinlist]
"SpamReporter"="1"
```

Furthermore. The assembly is signed with a Comodo Certificate in Visual Studio, and I have also tried to sign the installer itself again.

But all of these efforts seem to not make a difference. I thought I had a working version we could roll out, only to get the response from our rollout guy that the plugin doesn't show up for him when he tested it quickly.

This behaviour is really frustrating and the docs on Office 365 VSTO COM add-in troubleshooting seem really scarce.

I have spent an obscene amount of hours trying to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your addin takes too long to load (assuming it does not crash on startup).
Note that you get punished for using .Net - the whole .Net run-time of a particular version needs to be loaded before a single line of code in your addin runs. There used to be a Warmup registry key that allowed to tell Outlook whcih version of .Net run-time you are using so it will preload it, but it is no longer supported.

What does Outlook itself say when you go to File | Options | Addins | COM Addins?

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for the info on the loading behaviour of .NET, I wasn't aware that the entire framework has to be loaded. File | Options | Addins | COM Addins says (de translated:) "The selected Add-In has been activated by the system admin, but it has been deactivated, because it has hindered the proper functionality of Outlook"

Comment: Yep, that sounds a startup issue. Note that addins written in native languages (e.g. C++ or Delphi) are not subject to this limitation. You can also create a shim addin in a native language that loads your primary addin later when Outlook is not looking.

Comment: Also, if your addin does not need to set up any event handlers and only works when a user clicks on a ribbon button, you might want to mark it "load on demand" instead of "load on startup".

Comment: I found out that outlook kept an entry in Options | Add Ins | Manage: Deactivated Elements | Go that was blocking even my development runs from loading the AddIn in Outlook. I removed and now I can atleast run the AddIn via VS. I will now test and try to get a .msi build. Jesus Christ why is Outlook so finnicky. 3+ damn lists where AddIns can be managed / disabled. Give me a break.

Comment: Now I have the problem that Office 365 tells me and other users that when I try to add the AddIn via .vsto or .dll that the AddIn is not a valid outlook AddIn. However, my .vsto from my dev/project/bin/Release is always kept and used in Outlook (.vsto | vstolocal). The odd thing is that the install seems to work for Office 2016 and the AddIn is recognized and works, but not in Outlook 365. How is this possible?

Comment: Did you compile your addin as x86, x64, or Any CPU?

Comment: I compiled it as Any CPU

Comment: Real odd discovery. I created a x64 Preset and built the code project, then the Installer Project. Both with Debug & Release settings I get .tmp files and the .msi is missing. I have seen in another thread that they said this can be caused by F-Secure, which we have aswell.

Comment: I found that in the installer project properties it was still set to x86, I changed that x64 and installed the plugin. It's now loaded from the proper install directory. But now I am back to another issue. Outlook now says again it has caused a slow start (0,39s) and it has been disabled as a result. When I look in the AddIn list it says "not loaded, during loading of the COM Add In there has been a runtime error. The Add In has been activated by the system admin"

Comment: Thing is, when I "hot load" the Add In into Outlook with VS Debug it works just fine, but when it's installed via Installer it says it has the error.